# Apple trackpad disconnects every few minutes on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, touchpad, intel, apple

Connecting the apple trackpad 1 is easy, a great experience on Ubuntu, and I was impressed how many features work out of the box on my Ubuntu 22.04 box. However, the trackpad will periodically become unusable for a few moments (~1m), the Bluetooth icon disappears from the menu bar, and once it reappears, the disconnected trackpad reconnects.

There are a lot of scattered suggestions in posts across linux platforms. I've tried most of their proposed solutions:

- obviously a restart doesn't help (wishful thinking)
- nor the latest kernel upgrades (or last few reverts)
- disabling upower / tlp (I'm on a desktop, but suggested a few times) doesn't help
- disabling usb auto-suspend doesn't help
- disabling disable ESCO doesn't help
- setting UserspaceHID to false in `/etc/bluetooth/input.conf` no dice
- using a bluetooth dongle doesn't help (mine is Broadcom Corp. Bluetooth 4.0 btw)
- adding `btusb.enable_autosuspend=0` to `/etc/default/grub` nada
- reinstalling most Bluetooth related software
- and most other suggestions that I've forgotten at this point.

Is it my trackpad? I don't think so, given other people have this issue, and that it works fine paired to my MacBook. Is it power management? I tried to disable that to test it. Is it WiFi interference as some suggested? I could nuke my wireless for a day, but that doesn't seem much like a solution.

It seems random, at least by just looking at the intervals (here are the disconnect invervals from one day of work (a passtime while I waited for it to reconnect)). Time of day invariant.

ex. time between disconnects sequence: 10m, 50m, 11m, 2m, 4m, 3m, 3m, 25m, 4m, 31m, 49m, 8m, 44m, 20m

I know this isn't the newest issue, I've seen people complain about it since 15.10, but I really really really would love additional ideas on how to fix such an inconvenient problem.

This is doubtfully Ubuntu specific, and probably an issue with the kernel, [[hey look a bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204589) ] [[hey look similar bluetooth issues](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&component=Bluetooth&order=bug_status%20DESC%2Cpriority%2Cassigned_to%2Cbug_id&product=Drivers&query_format=advanced) ] but there are enough posts on this forum that maybe this will pull some traction.

Sure, it does force one to be a bit mindful during the workday, and once an hour even would be.. tolerable... but every 5 minutes... no...

Here's some dooblydoo, please let me know if there's something else to check that would be helpful!

Output from `lsusb |grep Bluetooth`:

`Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth`

some device info:

```
Device D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (public)
    Name: Trackpad (Home)
    Alias: Trackpad (Home)
    Class: 0x00002594
    Icon: input-tablet
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)

    Modalias: usb:v05ACp030Ed0160
```

Not much jumps out to me in the logs, and I can't find anything that is complaining before the disconnects. But please prove me wrong if I likely missed something. The closest to the disconnect events I could find are below:

`sudo btmon` good disconnect snippet (ie, the trackpad wakes instantly upon touch):

```
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18            #7442 [hci0] 144.274773
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 6c c3 16 af bf 87 f7 16 2a 42 80 43        .(l.......*B.C  
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18            #7443 [hci0] 144.286030
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 98 c3 16 af bf 87 f7 00 00 40 80 73        .(.........@.s  
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18            #7444 [hci0] 144.297376
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 c4 c3 16 af bf 87 f7 00 00 40 80 03        .(.........@..  
< ACL Data TX: Handle 256 flags 0x00 dlen 6             #7445 [hci0] 251.361210
      Channel: 140 len 2 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        43 47                                            CG              
< HCI Command: Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) plen 2     #7446 [hci0] 251.361236
        Handle: 256
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4               #7447 [hci0] 251.477954
      Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #7448 [hci0] 251.894073
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 256
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 7             #7449 [hci0] 251.916114
      Channel: 64 len 3 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a3 47 51                                         .GQ             
< ACL Data TX: Handle 256 flags 0x00 dlen 6             #7450 [hci0] 251.916340
      Channel: 140 len 2 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        43 47                                            CG              
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                  #7451 [hci0] 251.918064
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 256
        Mode: Active (0x00)
        Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5  #7452 [hci0] 251.923950
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 256
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 7             #7453 [hci0] 251.925745
      Channel: 64 len 3 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a3 47 51                                         .GQ             
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                  #7454 [hci0] 251.959078
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 256
        Mode: Sniff (0x02)
        Interval: 11.250 msec (0x0012)
```

and a bad "disconnect snippit" ie. I have to wait 1m for it to reconnect.

```
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18          #75425 [hci0] 7978.401187
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 68 9a 0c ae 42 75 fc 0a 0e c1 80 22        .(h...Bu....."  
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18          #75426 [hci0] 7978.411132
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 94 9a 0c ad 62 75 fc 07 0f c1 80 22        .(....bu....."  
< ACL Data TX: Handle 256 flags 0x00 dlen 6           #75427 [hci0] 7978.412946
      Channel: 140 len 2 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        43 47                                            CG              
< HCI Command: Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) plen 2   #75428 [hci0] 7978.412976
        Handle: 256
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4             #75429 [hci0] 7978.414081
      Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 18          #75430 [hci0] 7978.422658
      Channel: 65 len 14 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a1 28 c0 9a 0c ad 62 75 fc 08 10 c1 80 22        .(....bu....."  
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Pac.. (0x13) plen 5  #75431 [hci0] 7978.423168
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 256
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 256 flags 0x02 dlen 7           #75432 [hci0] 7978.423711
      Channel: 64 len 3 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        a3 47 51                                         .GQ             
< ACL Data TX: Handle 256 flags 0x00 dlen 6           #75433 [hci0] 7978.423869
      Channel: 140 len 2 [PSM 0 mode Basic (0x00)] {chan 65535}
        43 47                                            CG              
> HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6                #75434 [hci0] 7998.509880
        Status: Connection Timeout (0x08)
        Handle: 256
        Mode: Active (0x00)
        Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4        #75435 [hci0] 7998.511077
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 256
        Reason: Connection Timeout (0x08)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8   {0x0001} [hci0] 7998.511120
        BR/EDR Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Reason: Connection timeout (0x01)
> HCI Event: Connect Request (0x04) plen 10           #75436 [hci0] 8019.530859
        Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Class: 0x002594
          Major class: Peripheral (mouse, joystick, keyboards)
          Minor class: 0x25
          Limited Discoverable Mode
        Link type: ACL (0x01)
< HCI Command: Accept Connect.. (0x01|0x0009) plen 7  #75437 [hci0] 8019.530920
        Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Role: Central (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4             #75438 [hci0] 8019.531777
      Accept Connection Request (0x01|0x0009) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Role Change (0x12) plen 8                #75439 [hci0] 8019.680675
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Role: Central (0x00)
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11          #75440 [hci0] 8019.852923
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 256
        Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Link type: ACL (0x01)
        Encryption: Disabled (0x00)
< HCI Command: Read Remote Su.. (0x01|0x001b) plen 2  #75441 [hci0] 8019.853033
        Handle: 256
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4             #75442 [hci0] 8019.853652
      Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Max Slots Change (0x1b) plen 3           #75443 [hci0] 8019.862775
        Handle: 256
        Max slots: 3
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported... (0x0b) plen 11  #75444 [hci0] 8019.864668
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 256
        Features: 0xbd 0x02 0x04 0x38 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00
          3 slot packets
          Encryption
          Slot offset
          Timing accuracy
          Role switch
          Sniff mode
          Power control requests
          Power control
          Enhanced inquiry scan
          Interlaced inquiry scan
          Interlaced page scan
          AFH capable peripheral
< HCI Command: Remote Name R.. (0x01|0x0019) plen 10  #75445 [hci0] 8019.864729
        Address: D8:A2:5E:FC:38:3F (Apple, Inc.)
        Page scan repetition mode: R2 (0x02)
        Page scan mode: Mandatory (0x00)
        Clock offset: 0x0000
< ACL Data TX: Handle 256 flags 0x00 dlen 10          #75446 [hci0] 8019.864736
      L2CAP: Information Request (0x0a) ident 1 len 2
        Type: Extended features supported (0x0002)
```

Answer (score 0):

here are a fix suggested recompiling kernel.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1834085

Regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241764)